# How to play a video from launch on tvOS that is not hardcoded?

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos

I have spent more time on this then I care to admit...

If I hard code the video from a url it will launch just fine! However, if I set it in a variable for a reusable cell, it will not play on launch.

```
var vid: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playVideo()
}

func getVid(var url: String) {
    if url.hasPrefix("https://streamable.com/")  {
        let ending = String(url.characters.dropFirst(23))
        url =  "https://cdn.streamable.com/video/mp4-mobile/"+ending+".mp4"
    }
    vid = url
}

func playVideo(){
    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: String(vid))!)
    player?.play()
}
```

Comment: are you sure the URL is correct? What's the `player.error`?

Comment: Try moving `playVideo()` to `viewDidAppear()`

Comment: the URL works when I am click the cell  just not as an auto loaded feature

Comment: @DanielStorm I have tried that as well

Comment: What *cell* are you referring to? Could you add the code or a screenshot of how you're creating it in Interface Builder?